# Python Network Hours

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Really struggling with this one so any help would be much appreciated.

GOAL - workout the hours between two datetime columns excluding weekends and only taking the hours between the working times of 9 & 17.

Now I have reused a function that I use for network days but the output is wrong and I can't seem to figure out how to get it working.

As an example I have In my data a start date and end date that are as follows

> Start_Date = 2017-07-11 19:33:00
> End_Date = 2017/07/12 12:01:00

and the output I'm after is

> 3.02

However the function I do have is returning 16!

Function below -

````
    start = pd.Series(start)
    end = pd.Series(end)
    mask = (pd.notnull(start) & pd.notnull(end)) & (start.dt.hour >= 9) & (end.dt.hour <= 17) & (start.dt.weekday < 5) & (end.dt.weekday < 5)
    result = np.empty(len(start), dtype=float)
    result.fill(np.nan)
    result[mask] = np.where((start[mask].dt.hour >= 9) & (end[mask].dt.hour <= 17), (end[mask] - start[mask]).astype('timedelta64[h]').astype(float), 0)
    return result ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like what you need is `businesstimedelta`

```
import datetime
import businesstimedelta

start = datetime.datetime.strptime("2017-07-11 19:33:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
end = datetime.datetime.strptime("2017-07-12 12:01:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

# Define a working day rule
workday = businesstimedelta.WorkDayRule(
    start_time=datetime.time(9),
    end_time=datetime.time(17),
    working_days=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

businesshours = businesstimedelta.Rules([workday])

# Calculate the difference
diff = businesshours.difference(start, end)

print(diff)
```

Output:

```
<BusinessTimeDelta 3 hours 60 seconds>
```

https://pypi.org/project/businesstimedelta/

Comment: This looks a lot cleaner, thank you. I'm struggling a little but to take the above and use it in my situation. Is it possible to pass the columns to this to wok out for each row?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. This is just an example code to demonstrate the concept. You can refactor this into a function that takes start and end as arguments and returns the diff. Then incorporate it into your solution. If you find this helpful please consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

So, I really struggled finding out how to apply the above into a function but finally after much banging of the head came up with the below. Sharing for the next person in my situation. I wanted to convert to minutes so if not required just remove the *60 at the return

```
import datetime
import businesstimedelta

# Define a working day
workday = businesstimedelta.WorkDayRule(
    start_time=datetime.time(9),
    end_time=datetime.time(17),
    working_days=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

# Combine the two
businesshrs = businesstimedelta.Rules([workday])


def business_Mins(df, start, end):
    try:
        mask = pd.notnull(df[start]) & pd.notnull(df[end])
        result = np.empty(len(df), dtype=object)
        result[mask] = df.loc[mask].apply(lambda x: businesshrs.difference(x[start],x[end]).hours, axis=1)
        result[~mask] = np.nan
        return result * 60
    except KeyError as e:
        print(f"Error: One or more columns not found in the dataframe - {e}")
        return None


df['Contact_SLA'] = business_Mins(df, 'Date and Time of Instruction', 'Date and Time of Attempted Contact')
```